# Is it feasible to treat Kafka as an ultimate data storage that deprecates tradition SQL database?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, streaming, system-design

I want to seek some suggestions or feedback from **Kafka** gurus about this:

In our new system design, our architect decides to introduce Kafka as the streaming platform in the replace of MQ, which is pretty exciting. But at the same time, treat the kafka as the **eternal data storage** for 7 years to replace the oracle DB for messages which I just don't understand.

Here is the use case:

When application found there are some data missing(not there in the cache layer), we have to go back to data storage to get it back, previously it is from oracle db, and it works. But now, we have to go back to the **Kafka topic** to query that data. I know all the messages are persisted in the kafka cluster as the **log** format, and kafka has capabilities for us to query them, but now they are not used for data streaming purpose or building streaming application, they are used for normal data fetching at arbitrarily time in the future which sounds weird to me.

so the questions are:

1. Is it efficient to query data as fast as sql database?
2. All the log data in kafka are indexed or not? How can we query data like structural sql syntax(like name='xxx' and age = '13' and gender='m')?
3. I know there is an embedded database inside Kafka which is the **RocksDB**, how can we utilize it?
4. Kstream can help?